# Security Exception in C# for web development

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, .net, web-development-server

I am currently using C# to develop a website, I tried to use a data file to store some temporary data. I used System.IO.StreamReader and  System.IO.StreamWriter to modify the data. However, after I uploaded my file to the oneline server, I got the following exception when I ran my site:

```
[System.Security.SecurityException]: Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.
[Descritpion]:The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.
```

Afterwards, I tried to set the trust level by adding [trust level="Full"] in my web.config file between [system.web][/system.web].I got the following exception:

```
 This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the site administrator has locked access to this section using from an inherited configuration file.
```

I am wondering where this configuration file is and how I could resolve this issue? 
Thanks in advance!

**This problem is solved now,** the way to solve this is using MapPath("~/foldername/file") instead of directly using the path directory. It creates a virtual directory for which you can adjust the permission on Godaddy server.

Comment: What's the file you're trying to modify including the path?

Comment: does the storage folder have 'NetworkService' permission?

Comment: @ConradFrix the file is a simple text file and after I upload it onto the server, I can read it through internet.

Comment: @cinek I think I set the folder where the file is in to grant access for modification, I used godaddy.com to host my site, it has a file management section where I changed my setting